# Аналог плагина "Кто украл мои картинки?" в промышленных масштабах

Tags: php, плагин

Есть плагин к файрфоксу, который проверяет адреса сайтов, имеющих такую же картинку.
Каким образом реализовать это же на PHP?
Как всегда, интересует принцип, а то я даже разобрать строку запроса к гуглу не смог. =(

Comment: Проверяет сайты заранее известные или ищет сайты на которых есть ворованный имейдж?

З.Ы. Спрашиваю так как ФФ юзаю только для отточки кроссбраузерности. Поэтому плагин такой не знаю)

Comment: В данном частном случае - заранее известные, причем их количество довольно небольшое.   
Проблема в том, что картинки могут "немножко" отличаться - флипнуты, обрезаны, сжаты итп. Еще большая проблема, что сайт, на котором работает скрипт фторичен. то есть это на нем с большей вероятностью ворованный контент с указанного списка сайтов.   
Картинок ОЧЕНЬ много для человека (несколько тысяч или десятков тысяч).

Comment: Не знаю будет ли в тему, есть скрипт который иметирует поискового бота, т.е.сканирует html страницы. Если вкатить туда пару регулярок с массивами картинок, то я думаю что получится то что нужно. Короче однозначно его нужно докручивать под свои нужды.

Comment: Если через гугл - то только продолжать разбирать строку запроса) Как я понял, надо, чтобы начальный сайт был проиндексирован, а гуглю слать типа "пробей список картинок, похожих на эту(адрес)"

А если "на пхп", я бы забыл пхп, искал хостинг с cgi и кодил на сях. Ибо искать "частичные совпадения" на php, тем более, если нет индексированного списка картинок, это вам йо-хо-хо, два ящика рома и в отпуск до завершения поиска)

Comment: @Palmervan, не катит, по регулярке, которую я в состоянии "вкатить" он не сможет сравнить содержимое картинки. Изображение, то бишь.

@Shadow, ясно.. Буду просить у тиная предоставить аренду БД... =(

Comment: Кстати, [вот](http://umnet.ru/kak-najti-poxozhie-kartinki-s-pomoshhyu-google-kartinki/) мб тут что-то интересное найдете.

И [вот](http://tinyurl.com/cm5jls5) ссыль, где можно проследить все виды поиска, на всякий случай

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент я просматриваю Гуглхромовскую JS библиотеку этого плагина. Возможно, это поможет.

Comment: Библиотека допилена и прикручена. В общем, чаще всего, гугл не замечает подвоха.

Answer (score 0):

Есть сервис tineye со своим [API](http://www.tineye.com/commercial_api), но это платно. На php же все темно. Есть идея разделять изображения на части и усреднять значения цвета. Или же поворачивать и усреднять. Затем - записывать в БД, допустим, для разделений 4x4, 16x16 и 32x32 и поворотов +-20, +-10 и 0. А затем, собрав БД, можно будет уже сравнивать значения с нужной картинкой...
Вот только мутно все это, и я не уверен, что php подойдет для этих целей.